# Should "Intruding" be used here?

Tags: mesh

I would like to create a sunken area. 
[image]

I wonder what would be the best way to achieve this.
Should "intruding" (the opposite of extruding, I guess) be used here?
Scaling would not easily work because the neighbouring vertices would also be moved. I would have to introduce 2 extra ringcuts to avoid moving the neighbouring vertices.

Could anybody tell me the best way to achieve what I want?
Thank you.

Comment: It's kind of hard to tell what you are after from that picture, do you have a better reference image?

Comment: Unfortunately this is the best that I have. Should I extrude and then scale? Seems like the best option for me right now.

Comment: Try [Alt]+[E] > *vertex normals* or [E] > [S] > [Shift]+[Z].

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite know how to interpret the image, but here is a possibility:

Switch into edge or vertex selection mode. Press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to add a loop cut through the face ring in question, making sure to slide the new loop all the way down to the loop below it.

[image: adding edge loop]

Press <kbd>S</kbd> and then <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to scale the new edge loop while locking the Z axis to get something like this:

[image: after adding edge loop and scaling it down]

[image]